# pi_face_tracker in rosjava

Tags: java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm now trying to do item selection in rosjava. But I have problem on it. For the node pi_face_tracker, we need to get image form it, the msg type is image, but what we have form the camera is compressedimage. When we use the image_transfer node to transfer the image, what class in rosjava can i use? Can anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35316/pi_face_tracker-in-rosjava/) by [han](https://answers.ros.org/users/2284/han/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no implementation of image_transport of rosjava. However, depending on your use-case it may not be necessary. See the android_tutorial_image_transport for an example of how to work with nodes that expect to be communicating via image_transport.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0